# dynamically create a new instance of a class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I have a page which has contains 4 other widgets that get shown based on a BottomNavigationBar. Each of the widgets is loading it's data from an API call using the bloc pattern, while they fetch te data a loading widget is being shown. The first time each widget is selected all works as expected, the second time the widget is selected the old data is shown for a brief moment while the new data is being refreshed and before the loading animation is loaded.

I want a new instance is created every time the BottomNavigationBarItem is selected to avoid showing the previously loaded data.

My code so far:

```
  final List<Widget Function()> bodyWidgetList = [
    () => new HomePage(),
    () => new MyServicesPage(),
    () => new MyOrdersPage(),
    () => new MyBalancePage()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown],
    );
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
          statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          appBar: appBar(width),
          body: bodyWidgetList[_tabIndex](),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Inicio',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.business),
                label: 'Activos',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.analytics_outlined),
                label: 'Mis Servicios',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance),
                label: 'Mi Saldo',
              ),
            ],
            currentIndex: _tabIndex,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.redAccent,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
            onTap: (index) {
              setState(() {
                _tabIndex = index;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Sample page

```
class MyBalancePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyBalancePage createState() => _MyBalancePage();
}

class _MyBalancePage extends State<MyBalancePage> {
  
  BalanceBloc balanceBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    balanceBloc = BlocProvider.of<BalanceBloc>(context);
    balanceBloc.add(FetchBalanceEvent());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      bottom: false,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 16.0,
          right: 16.0,
          top: 0,
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: BlocBuilder<BalanceBloc, BalanceState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is BalanceInitialState) {
                  return Loading("Recuperando datos...");
                } else if (state is BalanceLoadingState) {
                  return Loading("Recuperando datos...");
                } else if (state is BalanceLoadedState) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            child: Text(
                              "Tu saldo actual es:",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontFamily: "Poppins-Bold",
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            child: Text(
                              "${state.balance.toStringAsFixed(2)} €",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.redAccent,
                                fontFamily: "Poppins-Bold",
                                fontSize: 50.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (state is BalanceErrorState) {
                  return Failure(state.message);
                }
                return Loading("Recuperando datos...");
              }),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added an example(different approach) for your question. Also, why don't create a new instance, because the list is a reference type variable so if you don't access the list item and update the, item doesn't create new instance.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown],
    );
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
          statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          appBar: appBar(width),
          body: _getSelectedWidget(_tabIndex),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Inicio',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.business),
                label: 'Activos',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.analytics_outlined),
                label: 'Mis Servicios',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance),
                label: 'Mi Saldo',
              ),
            ],
            currentIndex: _tabIndex,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.redAccent,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
            onTap: (index) {
              setState(() {
                _tabIndex = index;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  Widget _getSelectedWidget(int index){
    switch(index){
      case 0:
        return HomePage();
      case 1:
        return MyServicesPage();
      case 2:
        return MyOrdersPage();
      case 3:
        return MyBalancePage();
      default:
        return const SizedBox.shrink();
    }
  }

  }
```

Second way;

```dart
  final List<Widget Function()> bodyWidgetList = [
    () => new HomePage(),
    () => new MyServicesPage(),
    () => new MyOrdersPage(),
    () => new MyBalancePage()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown],
    );
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
          statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          appBar: appBar(width),
          body: bodyWidgetList[_tabIndex](),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Inicio',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.business),
                label: 'Activos',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.analytics_outlined),
                label: 'Mis Servicios',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance),
                label: 'Mi Saldo',
              ),
            ],
            currentIndex: _tabIndex,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.redAccent,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
            onTap: (index) {
              setState(() {
    switch(index){
      case 0:
       bodyWidgetList[index] = () => HomePage();
break;
      case 1:
       bodyWidgetList[index] = () => MyServicesPage();
break;
      case 2:
       bodyWidgetList[index] = () => MyOrdersPage();
break;
      case 3:
       bodyWidgetList[index] = () => MyBalancePage();
break;
      default:
        print('');
    }
                _tabIndex = index;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Yes, it's a reference type variable, that's why I want to create a new instance of the widget every time and not just reuse the existing one

Comment: I added a second way for your question